# Model has white Dots

Tags: materials, objects, object-mode

My model has white dots only in object mode and only in materials. They sometimes disappear if you look at the model from a different angle and it is not a texture problem.

[image: good old tardis model from a few days ago]

[image: Hey, look! Still dead vertices in my file]

[image]

Comment: You should also show your objects in the outliner windows of full screen height and determine if you have any objects which can be deleted.  There is undo in Blender.

Comment: You seem to have these extra spheres. Can select these items? Can you select a single one and delete? Archive your file before this if the file is valuable

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already saw that Tardis model a couple of days ago here on BSE either from a different user or from your "other account". It's still the same problem, there are tons of unnecessary and unconnected vertices in your mesh that need to be cleaned up. Switch to Vertex Select mode in Edit mode and you see what I mean.

Comment: After that time I have connected vertices that I could but some of white dots appear

Comment: Can you show an image of the topology? This way we could help in case it is actually bad topology or an other mistake

Comment: Did you mean that?
https://imgur.com/tRztKgS

Comment: Dude, please learn your ways around Stack Exchange. Use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/139103/edit) at the bottom of your question and add the missing information (like the image) to your question by [using the proper tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Besides... as I said - it's still the same problem it was the last time you asked the question. I can still clearly spot at least one dead vertex right beneath the lower panels. Also - please don't double-post or create new accounts for every question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "Remove Doubles" in the edit mode to remove the excess vertices

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: I already told him to remove doubles the first time he asked about what's wrong with his model.